# Convert warning to failure: ResourceWarning: unclosed <socket.socket

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, python-asyncio

When writing tests for code that uses sockets I sometimes get

```
ResourceWarning: unclosed <socket.socket ...
```

which I really like, as it pushes me to close the sockets deliberately in the code.

However, it would be better for me if the tests actually *fail* if this ever happens, rather than just showing a warning in the console.

How can this be done?